# Why am I getting weird font rendering with Dosis on Safari mobile?

Tags: html, css, fonts, safari, mobile-safari

I have a webapp that uses Dosis as its main font (http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Dosis), and it looks great every browser but Safari mobile, where my font is rendered like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1koB.jpg (The iPhone rendering is the one in the second image.)

The font is imported in this way:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis:200' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

If I increase the font weight the rendering is slightly better, but still weird.

I've tried few workaround with CSS, like:

```
* {
   font-weight: normal;
   text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
   -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
   font-smoothing: none;
}
```

but solved nothing.

Any idea on what is the reason of this strange behaviour?

***edit, one maybe important detail:***
that table is handled by `owlcarousel2` (https://github.com/OwlFonk/OwlCarousel2)

Comment: Can you show the CSS where you define font-family?

Comment: Odd — the font looks fine on [this example page](http://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/cdn.pauldwaite.me.uk/dosis.html) in Safari on my iPhone (iOS 8.0.2). How does that example page look in your version of mobile Safari?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite: your page looks ok (I don't hace Safari Mobile, everytime I should ask someone to check). I have to add that the table in the screenshot is handled by a javascript carousel (`owlcarousel2`)

Comment: @khilley: you can check it here: http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis:200

Comment: @marka.thore that's where you call the Google Font from Google. I'm asking if you have defined any inline or external CSS declaring the font within the HTML document to be displayed as Dosis?

Comment: @khilley: sorry I've read it too quickly. I have defined it in body, like this: `body{ font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif; }`

Comment: So two things to try out, looking at the screenshot. First, try checking if using the normal weight of the font helps (vs. the current extra-light style). To do so you'll need to change your Google Font URL instead to http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis'. Second, the following URL on Google Fonts says that the extra-light Dosis font is 'only useful at size 36pt and up': http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Dosis . Seems like you're trying to use it at a smaller size than it's optimal for, so perhaps try swapping out a different Google Font altogether?

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these: 

`-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%`

`-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;`


I have no explanation for this, just Googled it..

Comment: you should explain how it fixes the problem